# Mysql Delete and Timestamp

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp, delete-row

i looking for some help about MySQL, Very easy question, but really breaked my brain for some time.

i have a table called "logs", That have "date" thing, That is INT(11) of Timestamp, So, it use timestamp actual for it.

i gonna make a script that execute a SQL command each minute, That Check ALL rows, if "date" have more/equal than 6 hours, i tired so much, and nothing for help.

Some commands i used and won't worked.

```
DELETE FROM logs WHERE date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR));
DELETE FROM logs WHERE date < NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR;
```

Won't help, So, i asking here if you can help me, Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by 'INT(11) of Timestamp' ?

Comment: Why don't you use a real `TIMESTAMP` datatype?

Comment: if the `date` column contains a numeric timestamp, then the first query should work.

Comment: Describing the problem as "won't worked" is next to useless in providing meaningful information. Does the query return with 0 rows affected? Is it removing rows that shouldn't be removed? Is it returning an error?  In what way is it not working?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your date column must be of [Type TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html) and not INT in order to be able compare timestamps with each other properly, or you can write:

```
DELETE FROM logs WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR));
```

Comment: But MySQL does do automatic type conversion. And it's possible to compare integer values. we don't (normally) want to compare an integer value (32-bit unix-style number of seconds) to a DATETIME column.. the automatic conversion of the DATETIME to numeric works, but it returns a number like yyyymmddhhmmss, not a unix-style number of seconds.  Wrapping an integer expression in `FROM_UNIXTIME` does convert the integer to a value, but we don't (normally) want to compare that to the return from UNIX_TIMESTAMP. This answer was a swing and a miss.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
DELETE FROM logs
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR);
```

Answer (score 0):

The date "thing" is called a column. The column has a specific datatype. The question indicates that the column is datatype `INT(11)`. And in that column is stored unix-style 32-bit integer number of seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC.

If that's all true, then the first query form is appropriate. The expression on the right side (of the less than comparison) returns an integer number of seconds.

As a demonstration, consider this expression:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( NOW() + INTERVAL -6 HOUR )   ==> 1528450555
```

or, the way the original is written

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR))
```

returns an equivalent result.

---

The second query can be evaluated, but the automatic conversion from DATETIME to numeric will return us an integer value like `20180608153555`  (i.e. yyyymmddhhmmss), not number of seconds since the beginning of the epoch.

Consider a demonstration, DATETIME dataytpe evaluated in numeric context:

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL -6 HOUR + 0  ==>  20180608153600
```

If we use that expression, compare that to an INT(11) column, and delete all rows that have an INT(11) column less than that value, it's going to delete every row in the table that has a non-NULL value in that column.